# segmentation fault core dumped in c

Tags: linux, c

When I run this code I get the error **segmentation fault (core dumped)**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  printf("\n cmdline arg counts = %s ", argc);
  printf("\n exec name = %s ", argv[0]);
  for (i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    printf("\n arg %d = %s" , i, argv[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Tell me how to solve this. I am passing arguments.

Comment: How this is execute? What command is used to execute it? Please share it.

Comment: The error is so obvious that it will get closed as a typo if we move it to stackoverflow.com, where it belongs.  Your first `printf` considers `argc` as a string which makes it refer to that address which obviously doesn't exist.  Use `%d` instead of `%s`.

Comment: beside, on ubuntu I get a clear wrning at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the line:

```
printf("\ncmdline arg counts = %s ",argc );
```

You use %s (instead of %d) form printing argc, thus interpreting argc
as a pointer to a string. This makes printf try to read a string 
in a protected space.
Change the line to:

```
printf("\ncmdline arg counts = %d ",argc );
```

And all is well